# set id using setAttribute to td of last row of element

Tags: javascript, html

I am generating a table row which has two columns dynamically in html containing values from the database.
I want every td of the first column to have an unique id which i have done but i cant set the id to the td of last row in the table. 
Here's the code to set id

```
<script>
var i=0;
var id=1;
while(i<100)
{
document.getElementsByTagName("td")[i].setAttribute("id", id);
i=i+2;
id=id+1;
}
</script>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `while(i<102)` ???

Answer (score 1):

> but i cant set the id to the td of last row in the table.

You need to get to the last row in the table first.

```
var allRows = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
var lastRow = allRows[allRows.length - 1];
```

now set Id to the first td of last row

```
lastRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].setAttribute("id" , allRows.length + 1 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all first td's withing given table using [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child);
It will return [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)  which need to be convert into in an Array.

```
var arrTD = document.querySelectorAll("#list-notification tr td:first-child");

    arrTD = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrTD);

    var i =0;
    arrTD.forEach(function(val,key){ 
                  val.setAttribute('id',i);
                  ++i   
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

DOM Selectors are provided for a reason. :)

```
var tds = $('tr td:first-child');
var i=0;
$.each(tds, function(){
    $(this).attr('id',i++);
});
```

OR

Using pure javascript

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('tr td:first-child');
var i = 0;
for(var td in tds){
    tds[td].setAttribute('id',i++);
    // or
    //tds[td].id=(i++).toString();
};
```